# Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio 2012 different behaviour for the same code using the same C# version

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

This code runs on Visual Studio 2019 but fails to compile on Visual Studio 2012

```cs
Task.Factory.StartNew(HandleMessages);
```

```cs
public async Task HandleMessages()
{
   ...
}
```

Visual Studio 2012 shows this error

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew(System.Action)' and 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>(System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>)'

I can fix this error like this :

```cs
Task.Factory.StartNew<Task>(HandleMessages);
```

But I can't understand why does Visual Studio 2019 compile it without showing any error while Visual Studio 2012 rejects it.

I'm building an application using the following:

- Visual Studio Community 2019
- WinForms
- C# 5.0
- .Net Framework 4.5

I have the same setup for the Visual Studio 2012

Tried building the solution using MSBuild it shows the same error that Visual Studio 2012 does.

**I need to know why does Visual Studio 2019 accepts this code and if there is a way to make it behave the same way Visual Studio 2012 does.**

Comment: Visual Studio prior to 2015 uses the old compiler, whereas 2015+ uses Roslyn. It looks like the overload resolution rules were improved in Roslyn - it's not really a "breaking change", since the code wouldn't compile previously.

Comment: Previously you had the error due to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10034429/11683. Then you stopped getting the error due to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45236746/11683 (specifically the *"when passing method groups (as opposed to lambdas) to overloads expecting delegates"* part). I would expect the new rules to not apply when you choose C# v5.0 explicitly in the project settings, but apparently that controls only the available language features, not the overload resolution rules.

Comment: ... (which is apparently [hinted by](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#c-language-version-reference) *"The compiler accepts only syntax that is included in version 5"* as opposed to "The compiler behaves as if it was version 5")

Comment: That was very helpful, but I need MSBuild and Visual Studio both to show an error or allow the code otherwise it will only cause more issues for me

Comment: That's why it's called a "breaking change". If you need to use two VS versions, use those that are on the same side of the breaking change. I guess you could also manually point MSBuild to the compiler version included with VS 2012.