# How to get a unique id for a method based on its signature in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Is there anyway i could get a uniqueId for every method in a specific class using reflection based on its signature? I am aware of the GetHashCode method, but I want guaranteed uniqueness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How unique does it have to be? What size?

If you just concatenate the return type and every argument type using commas, you have a string that uniquely identifies this signature. It also happens to fully encode the signature, but that's not necessarily bad.

If you want something shorter, you could:

- hash it using a cryptographic hash function. Slow, the hash is long, but extremely likely to be unique
- hash it using a simple hash function. Collisions might occur, but the Id is shorter.
- store them in some sort of a lookup table or database. Your IDs are then just sequential integers.

Comment: i thought i could find an already builtin property or method in the MethodInfo class that has it, but i'll take urs as an answer

Answer (score 7):

Type.FullName + MemberInfo.Name + argument types for a method, anything shorter will not be unique.

If you want to scope it for particular type - no need for type's FullName. If you need it only at run-time - MemberInfo objects themselves are probably the best thing.

Comment: i was hoping to get a readable number, that would get me a very long string.

Comment: To get the unique method signature you also need to factor in number of type parameters and the method of passing each formal parameter. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8809191/1382376.

Answer (score 1):

Using the System.Reflection Namespace:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx

**Name of Method:**
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
**Type of method:**
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType
**Parameters of the method:**
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters().