# What is a method signature?

Tags: java, c#, methods, method-signature

I read a book titled 'Object First with Java' and in page 7 the author mentioned that the method signature "provides information needed to invoke that method". And the the author gave the following example:

```
void moveHorizontal(int distance)
```

However, today when I was watching a video about C# on Pluralsight, the author said that "the return type of a method is not part of the method signature".

I'm confused now and would like know **what is a method signature?**

Comment: [Google query](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=What+is+a+method+signature%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=3pQvVaC1AsyxsAHUtoLYDA) returns 9.400.000 results. Just saying.. You can also read Eric Lippert's answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8809191/447156

Comment: [Defining Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Answer (score 14):

A *method-signature* is the part of the method based on which you *overload / override* it. It contains :

> 1. The method name.
> 2. The arguments passed to it.

It doesn't contain :

> 1. Scope / access modifier
> 2. return type.

Comment: A bit add: *arguments* means types and order

Answer (score -1):

Method signature is used in interfaces and in abstract classes, but we always define the method data type(return type). It will be something invaluable if the return type is not a part of the signature.

Comment: The return type _is not_ part of the method signature - by definition.

Comment: It is also used in any class, not only on abstract ones or interfaces.

Comment: Iinterface { void Method1() ;   int Method2(int x, int y) ;}   these are examples of method signature, i used this way in interfaces, do you mean something else?