# Java method overriding of equals method

Tags: java, string, object, overriding

As, `equals()` method in **String class** is overridden method from Object class. And during overriding, change of signature is not allowed.

But `String.equals()` compares string values whereas `Object.equals()` compares reference values. So, is signature different in both classes? Or how it's done internally?

Comment: It is still `String#equals(Object)` so no, the signature is not changed. A quick look in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) would have told you this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a method signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672548/what-is-a-method-signature)

Comment: You need a tutorial on inheritence.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of both the classes is the same but the implementation is different.
For Object class:

```
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (this == obj);
    }
```

For String class the implementation is :

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = value.length;
        if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                    return false;
                i++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So when you call the equals method of String object it would call its overrided version of the method i.e implemented inside String class