# Method Overloading with out and optional parameter

Tags: c#, overloading

why overloading like this is working in c#?

```
public string DisplayOverload(string a, string b, string c = "c")
{
    return a + b + c;
}
public string DisplayOverload(string a, string b, out string c)
{
    c = a + b;
    return a + b;
}
```

while this is not working

```
public string DisplayOverload(string a, string b, string c = "c")
{
    return a + b + c;
}
public string DisplayOverload(string a, string b, string c)
{
    return a + b + c;
}
```

Comment: method overloading is based on number of arguments and type of arguments

Comment: The last 2 are the same signature. The first 2 are different because one has an out parameter.

Comment: The first may "work", but it's still a code smell. The do different things, so give them different names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`out` and `ref` are *considered* part of the method signature.

From [$3.6 Signatures and overloading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131%28v=vs.71%29.aspx);

> Note that any ref and out parameter modifiers (Section 10.5.1) are
>   part of a signature. Thus, `F(int)` and `F(ref int)` are unique
>   signatures.

Your second example, `c` is [optional argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx). Even if you call without this parameter value, 3 parameter overloaded method called but compiler *can't* know that which one to call.

For more information, check [Eric Lippert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8809191/447156) about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Method with output parameter will have different signature, while method with optional parameter may have the same signature.

**Works fine**

`DisplayOverload(string a, string b, string c)`

`DisplayOverload(string a, string b, out string c)`

**Will not work, since signature is the same**

`DisplayOverload(string a, string b, string c)` - optional `c` is always set either default or other value

`DisplayOverload(string a, string b, string c)`

Answer (score 0):

Because with the second pair of definitions the compiler wouldn't be able to tell `DisplayOverload("aa", "bb", "cc")` (when you mean it for the first function) from `DisplayOverload("aa", "bb", "cc")` (when you mean it for the sencond one).

On the other hand it's quite easy for the compiler to distinguish `string c; DisplayOverload("aa", "bb", c)` and `string c; DisplayOverload("aa", "bb", out c)`. Notice the `out` in the last call.