# Can a method be overloaded to return different types without a unique parameter list in its signature? In C#

Tags: c#

I have two identical methods, one returns a Vector2 and the other a Vector 3. For convenience I'd like to not have different method names.

If I declare a variable like this

```
private Vector2 to;
```

...and call a method that returns a type on it

```
to = getMousePosition();
```

I would like it to automatically use the Vector2 method, so it should return a Vector2. I don't know if this is possible however as when I try I'll get this console error

```
A member `DrawBouncingLine.getMousePosition()' is already defined. Rename     this member or use different parameter types
```

Which is reasonable enough. But I was wondering all the same.

The method I use looks like this

```
private Vector3 getMousePosition()
{
    Vector3 _mousePosition = new Vector3 (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y, 0);
    return _mousePosition;
}

private Vector2 getMousePosition()
{
    Vector2 _mousePosition = new Vector2 (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y);
    return _mousePosition;
}
```

Comment: No, you can't. This is because the return type is not part of the method signature. See this post for more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808703/method-signature-in-c-sharp In theory (very very general), this would be possible if the compiler did type-inference checks and then explicitly typed every assignment.

Comment: In C# overloading works only for parameters, not for the return type. Have searched on that in the past too. You must given different names to both methods.

Comment: Return types are not part of signature and you can't have two methods with same signature!